# Shorten queries to Linked server similar to USE command

Tags: sql-server, scope, sql-server-2014, linked-server

In SQL server, normally I would execute a `USE [my_db]` command at the beginning, so that for subsequent queries, I could use the shortened query form

```
SELECT * from [my_shema].[my_table]
```

instead of fully qualifying the query

```
SELECT * from [my_db].[my_shema].[my_table]
```

For linked server, it seems I need to always fully qualify the query as

```
SELECT * from [my_linkedserver].[my_db].[my_shema].[my_table]
```

Is there a similar approach to shorten query, by indicating that the default scope is `[my_linkedserver].[my_db]` ? `USE [my_linkedserver].[my_db]` does not seem to be the answer.

Comment: Creating a [SYNONYM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) seems to be the way to achieve this as suggested in [Using 4 part identifiers when database may be on the same server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74567)

Comment: Thanks Filburt. SYNONYM seems like a great solution. Yet SYNONYM can only pinpoint to specific objects such as tables/views https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1412457-391-1.aspx
I would like to shorten the part before that, `[my_linkedserver].[my_db]` or `[my_linkedserver].[my_db].[my_schema]`. Besides, if in the end we still need 4-part qualifier `[dbo].[my_synonym].[my_schema].[my_table]` instead of `[my_linkedserver].[my_db].[my_shema].[my_table]` then it's not really winning, is it ?

Comment: Admittedly you have to create a dedicated synonym for every object but it will allow you to use it like `[my_schema].[my_synonym]` - the whole 4-part qualifier will be masked by your synonym - you just need to `USE` the db you created the synonym in and you get usage of your first example.